# Proof that area obeys countable additivity

Tags: probability, integration, area

**Disclaimer**: I am reading introduction to statistics by Hogg, McKean and Craig, therefore, don't be harsh on any lack of probability knowledge.

**Background**: A question I encountered was "probability that a randomly picked 2-tuple in $\Omega \equiv [\vec x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \vert\vert \vec x \vert\vert <1]$ falls into $C$, a subset of $\Omega$." where $\vert\vert \vec x \vert\vert$ is just the Euclidean distance from origin. Now intuition tells me that the probability must be dependent on the area of the set $C$, divided by $\pi$. So I sort of "conjecture" a probability for this situation as such:$\forall B \subseteq \Omega$ $$P(B \subseteq \Omega) \equiv \frac{Area(B)}{\pi}$$

Before I move on I define my area set function as:$$Area(B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2) \equiv \iint_{B} dx dy$$ I hope there's no trouble with this area definition.

It was easy to check that this definition of probability obeyed the rules:

1. $\forall \ B \subseteq \Omega$ $0 \leq P(B) \leq 1$
2. $P(\emptyset)=0$
3. $P(\Omega)=1$

The last part is where I am stuck at, to show that:
given a sequence of disjoint sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $ [B_i]_{1}^{\infty} $

$$ P(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_i)=\frac{Area(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_i)}{\pi}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P(B_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{Area(B_i)}{\pi} $$
$$\implies Area(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}Area(B_i)$$

**Question**:How would one show this?
(*Technically, now I don't think this is any longer a "probability" question but rather an integration theory question.....*)

My attempt was futile, but my thought process was:
Given an infinite sequence of disjoint sets $B_i, i \in \mathbb{N}$
define: $$T_j= \cup_{i=1}^j B_i$$
We have that:

1. $\cup_{j=1}^{\infty}T_j=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_i$
2. $T_{j+1}=T_j \cup B_{j+1}$
3. $T_{j+1}-B_{j+1}=T_{j}\implies T_j \cap B_{j+1} =\emptyset$
4. $T_{1}=B_{1}$

Let's say we know area is finite additive, as in, given finite disjoint sets, the area of the union is the sum of the individual areas.
$$\implies Area(T_{j} \cup B_{j+1})=Area(T_{j+1})=Area(T_{j})+Area(B_{j+1})$$
$$\implies Area(T_{j+1})-Area(T_{j})=Area(B_{j+1})$$

$$\implies Area(B_1) + \sum_{j=1}^n \big(Area(T_{j+1})-Area(T_{j})\big)=\sum_{j=1}^n Area(B_{j})$$
Taking the limit, we get:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} Area(T_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} Area(B_i)$$

Now, ***if***, and its a big ***if***, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} Area(T_n)= Area(\lim_{n \to \infty} T_n)=Area(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_i)$$ Then were done.

But I wasn't able to prove the above statement. A proof of either the above statement, or just the general countable additivity of area using any other method is welcome. Any thoughts on the assumptions and approach are also welcome.

Comment: As you've indicated, that the area of an infinite union of disjoint measurable sets is the sum of the measures of those sets is a theorem of integration theory, and depends on specifics of how area is defined, not the vague notions you are playing around with here. Look up Lebesgue integration for details. One thing you are overlooking is that the union of the $B_i$ is contained in the unit circle, and thus cannot exceed $\pi$ in total area. The summation of the $B_i$ is a summation of non-negative values which is bounded above, and therefore must converge.